# How to save image on specific folder in java

Tags: java, jsp

how to save an image in a certain Directory ?

```
private void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws Exception
{

    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
    os.close();

}
```

The preceding code does not work properly. Any Suggestions.?

Comment: "It's not working" isn't clear at all. Please explain exactly what the problem is (file not being created? An exception is thrown?). Be specific.

Comment: image not save in my folder

Comment: I think you might wanna try creating the file first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws Exception
{
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationFile)));

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) 
    {
        bos.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing `BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationFile)));`    use this
`OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myDirectory+"\\"+destinationFile));` this will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Either specify the directory in the destinationFile itself (by the caller of saveImage), or add it in saveImage:

```
File outFile = new File(myDirectory, destinationFile);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the 4th line that is currently

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
```

with the following line, all the other lines should remain the same

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationFile));
```